# R: How to join dataframes with a key that has duplicate values, and COPY the second frame's values to each duplicate?

Tags: r, join, duplicates

I'm trying to join two dataframes. One is home sale data and the other is distance from a railroad. I am trying to join the data using a parcel ID as a key. The parcel ID in the sales data will have multiple values, because the parcels have sold several times. I want the data to join so that the distance values will repeat for each instance of the parcel ID, something like this.

Dataframe A:

| ID | Sale Date | Sale Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1/1/2020 | 320000 |
| 123 | 2/1/2021 | 429000 |
| 124 | 3/1/2019 | 190000 |
| 124 | 2/13/2020 | 280000 |
| 124 | 1/1/2022 | 419000 |
| 125 | 2/1/2021 | 300000 |
| 125 | 1/1/2022 | 390000 |
| 126 | 2/1/2021 | 310000 |

Dataframe B:

| ID | Distance |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1290 |
| 124 | 1809 |
| 125 | 370 |
| 126 | 976 |

I want the joined dataframe to look like this:

| ID | Sale Date | Sale Price | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1/1/2020 | 320000 | 1290 |
| 123 | 2/1/2021 | 429000 | 1290 |
| 124 | 3/1/2019 | 190000 | 1809 |
| 124 | 2/13/2020 | 280000 | 1809 |
| 124 | 1/1/2022 | 419000 | 1809 |
| 125 | 2/1/2021 | 300000 | 370 |
| 125 | 1/1/2022 | 390000 | 370 |
| 126 | 2/1/2021 | 310000 | 976 |

The distance values are copied for each parcel ID. When I use left_join I'm getting a new dataframe with more rows than either of the original dataframes (which is one problem) with a lot of NA values for distance (which is another problem). I don't understand why my new dataframe is larger than the largest of the original dataframes, and I don't know how to make it so that distance is repeated across each instance of the parcel ID and not just copied once and then NA thereafter.

When I searched for a solution for this problem, I mostly found methods of dropping duplicate rows, which I don't want. I want the rows in dataframe B to be copied for each instance of the ID in dataframe A.

Comment: Maybe you should also show your code for `left_join` and the results? I have no problem generating your desired output using `left_join`

Comment: My code is `frameC<- left_join(frameA, frameB, by="id")`.  I understand now that under normal circumstances, the output I need will be produced with that code, but since I'm not getting that output, there must be something else going on, maybe something to do with my data. Can you think of a reason why I'm having these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left_join` by your `ID` from the `dplyr` package. You can use the following code:

```
df_A <- data.frame(ID = c(123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 125, 125, 126),
                   Sale_Date = c("1/1/2020", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2019", "2/13/2020", "1/1/2022", "2/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "2/1/2021"),
                   Sale_Price = c(320000, 429000, 190000, 280000, 419000, 300000, 390000, 310000))

df_B <- data.frame(ID = c(123, 124, 125, 126),
                   Distance = c(1290, 1809, 370, 976))

library(dplyr)
df_joined <- left_join(df_A, df_B, by = "ID")
df_joined
```

Output:

```
   ID Sale_Date Sale_Price Distance
1 123  1/1/2020     320000     1290
2 123  2/1/2021     429000     1290
3 124  3/1/2019     190000     1809
4 124 2/13/2020     280000     1809
5 124  1/1/2022     419000     1809
6 125  2/1/2021     300000      370
7 125  1/1/2021     390000      370
8 126  2/1/2021     310000      976
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this is how it's supposed to work now. 

My data isn't doing that, which is telling me that there must be a problem somewhere else that I need to identify. My two datasets are very large and they have a lot of columns. Can you think of a reason why my join would be having the problems I described? i.e. producing a new dataframe with many more rows than either of the joined dataframes, and with a lot of NA values for the distance variable?